# How to clear labels after catching an error?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have an online form where there are many text boxes including email ID, passwords and other details. When user does not input the correct information. I am showing an error message shown in the below code. I am using the return values from SQL. I am trying to clear the labels for every button click. Can anyone help me?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {

            {
                SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(strCon);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateRequestAccess_Test", sqlCon);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "UpdateRequestAccess_Test";
                cmd.Connection = sqlCon;

                ----------Parameters are declared here--------

                SqlParameter rpv = new SqlParameter();
                rpv.DbType = DbType.Int32;
                rpv.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(rpv);
                try
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                    int retValue = Convert.ToInt32(rpv.Value);


                        if (retValue == 10)
                            lblMessage.Text = "Request was sent successfully!";

                        if (retValue == 11)
                            Label2.Text = "*Email Address is already registered.";

                        if (retValue == 12)
                            Label3.Text = "*Passwords do not match.";

                        if (retValue == 13)
                            Label4.Text = "Sorry, Your application was already denied earlier.";

                        if (retValue == 14)
                            Label5.Text = "*Please select an option 'Yes' or 'No' under Select Online Tools.";

                        if (retValue == 15)
                            Label6.Text = "*Please enter the information in the text boxes above.";

                        if (retValue == 15)
                            Label7.Text = "*Please Select an option from the dropdown above.";

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;

                        Label2.Text = ex.Message;

                        Label3.Text = ex.Message;

                        Label4.Text = ex.Message;

                        Label5.Text = ex.Message;

                        Label6.Text = ex.Message;

                        Label7.Text = ex.Message;

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `Label.Text = "";`? I'm not quite sure what you're having a problem with.

Comment: Once I click on the button if there are any errors it shows message. That is fine. After I make the changes and click on the button again the previous error message will still be there because it not cleared from catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put ClearTextMsg(); into your page load event.

If you use if(!IsPostBack) { } code block in page load then put it out side of that.

Perfect position is the first line of page load event. like following

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ClearTextMsg();
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
        // any valid c# statments
     }
}

// call this function
private void ClearTextMsg()
{
lblMessage.Text = "";
Label2.Text = "";
Label3.Text = "";
Label4.Text = "";
Label5.Text = "";
Label6.Text = "";
Label7.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try..

```
lblMessage.Text = "";
Label2.Text = "";
Label3.Text = "";
Label4.Text = "";
Label5.Text = "";
Label6.Text = "";
Label7.Text = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
Label2.Text = ex.Message;
Label3.Text = ex.Message;
Label4.Text = ex.Message;
Label5.Text = ex.Message;
Label6.Text = ex.Message;
Label7.Text = ex.Message;
```

try adding those lines in the beginning of your code, just above the `try` on your try-catch statement.

or maybe you can do

```
Label7.Clear();
```

Not sure with the syntax though, I'm a vb.net programmer :)

Answer (score 1):

update your button click event like below

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
                    lblMessage.Text = string.Empty;

                    Label2.Text = string.Empty;

                    Label3.Text = string.Empty;

                    Label4.Text = string.Empty;

                    Label5.Text = string.Empty;

                    Label6.Text = string.Empty;

                    Label7.Text = string.Empty;


    {

        {
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(strCon);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateRequestAccess_Test", sqlCon);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "UpdateRequestAccess_Test";
            cmd.Connection = sqlCon;

            ----------Parameters are declared here--------

            SqlParameter rpv = new SqlParameter();
            rpv.DbType = DbType.Int32;
            rpv.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(rpv);
            try
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                int retValue = Convert.ToInt32(rpv.Value);


                    if (retValue == 10)
                        lblMessage.Text = "Request was sent successfully!";

                    if (retValue == 11)
                        Label2.Text = "*Email Address is already registered.";

                    if (retValue == 12)
                        Label3.Text = "*Passwords do not match.";

                    if (retValue == 13)
                        Label4.Text = "Sorry, Your application was already denied earlier.";

                    if (retValue == 14)
                        Label5.Text = "*Please select an option 'Yes' or 'No' under Select Online Tools.";

                    if (retValue == 15)
                        Label6.Text = "*Please enter the information in the text boxes above.";

                    if (retValue == 15)
                        Label7.Text = "*Please Select an option from the dropdown above.";

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                    lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;

                    Label2.Text = ex.Message;

                    Label3.Text = ex.Message;

                    Label4.Text = ex.Message;

                    Label5.Text = ex.Message;

                    Label6.Text = ex.Message;

                    Label7.Text = ex.Message;

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I will try it and let you know.